# SseEmitter with proxy

Tags: java, spring, server-side, server-sent-events

I have an issue with SSE in my spring application.

When I run my code on my local environment it work perfectly.

But when I deploy my application on my server, I can't get a response from my SseController

here is my code

```
  @GetMapping("/api/sse/connect")
public SseEmitter getConnexion(){
    if(sseEmitters == null){
        sseEmitters = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    sseEmitters.add(emitter);
    emitter.onCompletion(() -> sseEmitters.remove(emitter));
    return emitter;
}
```

The problem is, when the application is on the server, the request for /api/sse/connect don't get any response from the server, but other controller which return values work

I thought it may be a proxy issue, but I can't find any information regarding this error

Hope you can help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which proxy do you use?
Some proxies need special configurations (`content-length`, headers, etc.) to support SSE and some don't (like the AWS load balancer (at least last year)).

Comment: It's a corporate proxy, I don't have much information  about it, my application is hosted on AWS.
The issue is that my request stay in pending when my application is on AWS. But when I run the application on my local environment, there is no issue :/

Comment: AWS load balancer didn't support SSE (at least in 2017, I haven't check whether they fix the issue): there is/was a timeout in the request and the connection gets closed after a while which is a pity for SSE... But if you don't receive anything, it might also comes from your corporate proxy.
May be you could check by proxying your app on AWS with a nginx that does support SSE (https://serverfault.com/a/801629).